# Sum while in Python?

Tags: python

For instance let's say I want to sum up all x^2 (or any other arbitrary function) for x=1 onward until x^2 is greater than n. Can this be done without using a bunch of while loops and if-checks?

Comment: You don't specificy the increment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The itertools modules has some nice functions for an extensible solution:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

def sum_func(func, n):
    return sum(takewhile(lambda x: x < n, (func(i) for i in count(1))))
```

For example:

```
>>> sum_func(lambda x: x**2, 20)  # 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2
30
```

If you want to make this also work with decreasing functions, you could also just pass in the test function:

```
def sum_func(func, pred):
    return sum(takewhile(pred, (func(i) for i in count(1))))
```

Example:

```
>>> sum_func(lambda x: -x*2, lambda x: x > -10)  # -1*2 + -2*2 + -3*2 + -4*2
-20
```

Comment: I like this one because I only have to write out the actual function once; what does takewhile and imap do?

Comment: [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) will yield elements from an iterable (second argument) until the first argument (which is a function) returns false for a value from the iterable.  [imap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) calls a function for each element in the iterable and yields the results of the function call.

Comment: I just realized that, unlike the other answers, this one doesn't do x**2 (or whatever the function is) twice, and it makes it very obvious how to do this for "any arbitrary function", so my answer is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

```
>>> sum(x ** 2 for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x ** 2 <= 100, itertools.count(1)))
385
```

Comment: You probably want to transform the sequence first, then filter it (as in F.J's answer), instead of the other way around (as in this). For `x**2` it scarcely matters, but for "any other arbitrary function"—which could be expensive or, worse, have side effects—you don't want to call it twice like this.

Answer (score 1):

dont you just need to do ...

```
max_val = 144   
sum(x**2 for x in range(sqrt(max_val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `x` incremented by 1 each time?

If so, this reduces to the following formula: `x(x+1)(2x+1)/6`, since it's [sum of the squares of integers](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/integration/sums.html).

So you really want to avoid loops, you can solve for `x(x+1)(2x+1)/6 < n` directly

Comment: "or any other arbitrary function"

Answer (score 0):

> sum up all x^2
>   until x^2 is greater than n

```
sum = 0
x = 1
while x**2 <= n:
    sum += x**2
    x += 1
```

One `while` loop, no `if`s.

If you'd rather use a `for` loop:

```
import itertools

sum = 0
for x in itertools.count(1): # Generates an infinite series: 1, 2, 3, ...
    square = x**2
    if square > n:
        break
    sum += square
```

One `for` loop, one `if`. Hardly "a bunch".